# How many session variables per user is considered too much? - PHP

Tags: php, session

If I have a website where users login and logout, and each user has 4 session variables being used, how will this affect my site?

Say if I have 100,000 active members, then that would be effectively 400,000 session variables being passed at the same time. Will this affect the loading of my site? I understand php has a memory limit but do not fully understand it.

Thanks

Comment: You have a website with 100,000 simultaneously active users? Good job!

Comment: Most of the overhead is going to be per session, not per session variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many variables is to many when storing in _SESSION?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681277/how-many-variables-is-to-many-when-storing-in-session)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4 variables per user is nothing, but my suggestion would be on a different level: Focus on what's causing actual bottlenecks in your web site. This issue is probably not relevant right now, and is really easy to switch from in the future if this what slows you down. (And it won't)

I bet you have much more important stuff to work on than worry about another variable, and when you get to that amount of active users, your whole structure will probably change, including servers and solutions. Good luck!

Comment: Again - the important thing is to establish a performance baseline, get some hard data, and draw some quantifiable conclusions about what will scale ... and what won't.  Worrying about something like "#/variables in a PHP session" is worse than useless at this point...

Answer (score 1):

To answer shortly - yes, it will affect loading of your site, if you have 100k users. But it won't be **only** because of sessions, they will be a part of the bottleneck.

It's easy to calculate possible memory consumption and according to that you should decide how to scale your site.
Scaling options are endless (well, as a phrase of course, there's a finite amount of ways to scale programs but still there are many to choose).

If it happens that you attract that many users, chances are you will be able to afford professional help when it comes to scaling your site.

If it's a case of you wondering what those options are, then it might be the best to ask a question with specific things in mind that trouble you when determining when and where the bottlenecks might be.

Also, you don't deploy sites with so many active users on a single server, using default PHP configuration, especially the session one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, of course, is "it depends".

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Establish a "performance baseline"

2) Consider resources like CPU, memory, network and disk

3) Consider OS, Web server, Application and database

4) Run stress tests, and compare your performance between "normal loads" to "high loads"

5) Identify the bottlenecks, and deal with them appropriately

Assuming you're running Linux/Apache/MySql (a total guess on my part - you didn't say), here's an excellent three-part article that might get you started in the right direction:

- [Tuning LAMP systems, Part 1: Understanding the LAMP architecture](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tune-lamp-1/index.html)

But trust me: worrying about minutia like whether you have 5 session variables instead or 4, instead of trying to gather solid baseline statistics, is NOT going to help you scale to 100,000 users :)!